# Should I always generate a unique Id and Name for every <input> element I submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I always generate unique id and name for every input I want to submit,

```
<input name='text1'/>
<input name='text2'/>
```

However I feel like using name array is more comfortable.

```
<input name='text[]'/>
<input name='text[]'/>
```

Does name array have identity problem or any other con?

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Maybe he means a name like that: data[username]

Comment: I mean,I always use <input name='text1'/><input name='text2'/>
but we can use <input name='text[]'/> so I wonder if this array of name effect the element identity or not

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and see what happens?

Comment: Sheez people here are so harsh.

Comment: @mplungjan +1 for your comment. people should really stop to think about whether the question really is hard to understand of if it's their own problem for not understanding it. People tend to click `close` when they should be clicking `-1`.

Comment: You don't need the brackets at all. You can just use `text` as their name. Makes it easier to access the elements via `form.text` in JavaScript.

Comment: or form["text[]"] if brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use PHP, the array you get when using [] is very convenient to gather fields of similar type.

From a javascript point of view, there are no issues other than the slight inconvenience to use form["text[]"] or form.elements["text[]"] to access the fields

Comment: Btw. if he is not using PHP, just using `text` is simpler.

Comment: Which is stated where exactly?

Comment: In the history of answers and questions.

Comment: Well, I would say if a question is not linked to a previous one, then the history should not matter. I mean, the question is not tagged as `php`. I'm also not saying you are wrong, I'm just saying if he does not send the values to PHP, omitting the brackets makes it easier to access the elements in JavaScript. But everything else is fine :)

Comment: Sure. I am just trying to be helpful :) - woa, SO just told us to [get a room](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555628/pro-con-of-html-inputs-name-array/6555750#) ;)